# React / Redux Component get unused params

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have container, for example, Home:

```
function mapStateToProps (state) {
  return {...state.home}
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return ....
}
class Home extends React.Component {

    constructor (props, context) {
        super(props, context);
    }

    render(){

        return (
            <div>
                <HeaderHome {...this.props.header}/>
                ...
            </div>
        )
    }

}

Home.contextTypes = {
    router: PropTypes.object
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Home);
```

Pay attention on  component it is very simple:

```
class Header extends React.Component {
    render(){

        return (
                <div className="tp__header-menu">
                    <Menu />
                    ....
                </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Header;
```

At the header i can use {this.props} which transferred from Home, also in Header a have Menu component to which I am not transferring some props!

Menu component:

```
function mapStateToProps (state) {
  return {...state.configuration.menu}
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return ...
}

class Menu extends React.Component {
    constructor(props, context){
        super(props, context);
    }


    render(){
        return (....)
    }
}

Menu.contextTypes = {
    router: PropTypes.object
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Menu);
```

Despite that i don't transferred props to this component, after console.log i see all props from  component and all props which transform from state to props. Why?

I want see only props which transform to props from state (store)

Comment: what are you expecting `...` to do in returns? i.e.  `return ...`

Comment: Its only example in the real code this method returns { ..... }